# Bios update - no bootable device

Tags: uefi, bios, software-updates

I made a bios update ↓
http://www.gigabyte.pl/products/page/mb/ga-x99-ultra_gamingrev_10#support-dl
from F6 to F7c.

Currently I am unable to start my computer. I have a message
"reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media ..."
I did downgrade from F7c to F6 (original version) it's still the same.

Detects the disk but not the "UEFI partition". The drive is "Intel 256GB M.2 2280 PCI-E x4 Gen3 NVMe SSD (SSDPEKKW256G7X1)"

I have the correct disk boot setup. My OS Arch Linux

Comment: You should upgrade again. But change in UEFI, normally resets many settings. Back with BIOS all settings were changed to default. Now with UEFI some settings like default boot are kept, but you may need to change drives to AHCI, turn on full USB support, turn off Secure Boot, and any other settings you previously changed. Did you also update firmware on NVMe drive?

Comment: I don't know now ... Probably the work with flash bios was around kernel work. Quite strange, because after the bios update I couldn't get to Grub. As I already fixed Grub → https://blog.tomlot.eu/naprawa-i-uporz%C4%85dkowienie-grub-2, I couldn't load the kernel. I had to pull the kernel from & fallback.img